# Checkbox True/False - Add To A Calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I've been Googling for hours and can't seem to find a solution that matches my query.

I'm trying to create a contact form (using Contact Form 7 on Wordpress), where each user input corresponds to a $ value, which is calculated and displayed live using `.innerHTML`.

The `type=number` user inputs work and calculate fine, but I cannot figure out how to have the checkbox contribute to the calculation according to whether the checkbox is checked, or unchecked.

The code I'm using is below, where `#pages` and `#images` are a simply `type=number` input, `#gallery` is the checkbox that I'm having issues with:

```js
$('#pages').on('change', function() {
 calculateTotal();
});
$('#images').on('change', function() {
 calculateTotal();
});
$('#gallery').on('change', function() {
 calculateTotal();
});
function calculateTotal() {
var pages = document.getElementById('pages');
var images = document.getElementById('images');
var gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');
var totalPages = pages.value * 15;
var totalImages = images.value * 10;
var totalGallery = 0;
if (gallery.checked == true){
totalGallery = 30 } 
else { totalGallery = 0}
var totalCost = 60 + totalPages + totalImages + totalGallery;
document.getElementById('displayTotal').value = "$" + totalCost;
}
```

As mentioned, I'm using the Contact Form 7 plugin for Wordpress, so contact form code is a mixture of shortcode and HTML:

```html
<div class="quote-left"><label>Number of pages:*[number* number-31 min:0 max:100 id:pages]</label></div>

<div class="quote-left"><label>Number of images:*[number* number-31 min:0 max:100 id:images]</label></div>

<div class="quote-left">[checkbox checkbox-779 id:gallery label_first "Photo gallery / photo slideshow:"]</div>

<div class="quote-left">[checkbox checkbox-996 id:social label_first "Social media links and optimisation:"]</div>

<div class="quote-right">[checkbox checkbox-996 id:legal label_first "Legal information (cookies disclaimer, privacy policy etc):"]</div>

<div class="quote-right">[checkbox checkbox-996 id:email label_first "Email & subscriber integration:"]</div>

<div class="quote-right">[checkbox checkbox-996 id:logos label_first "Logo / branding:"]</div>

<div class="quote-right">[checkbox checkbox-996 id:domain label_first "Domain and hosting:"]</div>

[textarea textarea-713]

<label>Total cost:</label>
[text text-387 readonly id:displayTotal placeholder "$60"]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the problem - what behaviour are you getting? Is the value of "totalGallery" not being changed if gallery is checked? Could you include the html?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The output I am getting in "displayTotal" when checkbox is checked is NAN. Which I know is "not a number", but can't figure out why it is throwing that out.

Comment: I've suggested a solution in the answer. If that's not the problem, could you tell me what the console shows if you write console.log(totalCost)?

Comment: The console shows "Uncaught ReferenceError: totalCost is not defined". The function executes fine when I update the number inputs, but does not add the checkbox input to the calculation. So I'm assuming that I'm missing something that is not properly executing the checkbox as a number (as opposed to boolean? (I'm not entirely sure how checkboxes work as far as JS is concerned)).

Comment: Could you please share the relevant HTML of #pages, #images and #gallery?

Comment: I don't have the space to provide the extra code in a comment, so I have updated my original question.

Comment: Where are you writing console.log(totalCost)?

Comment: You should do
console.log(pages.value, images.value, gallery.checked);
and see if you get an error.

Comment: is the answer working for you?

Comment: Nothing seems to be working yet ...

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the below snippet, when your try to add `number + undefined` you get `NaN`

```js
var number = 5;
var undefinedVar;

console.log(number + undefinedVar)
```

At start your values are undefined, so I have put a ternary operator, if value is undefined use default value as 0

```js
var pages = document.getElementById('pages');
var images = document.getElementById('images');
var gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');


$('#pages').change(function() {

 calculateTotal();
});
$('#images').change(function() {
 calculateTotal();
});
$('#gallery').change(function() {
 calculateTotal();
});
function calculateTotal() {
var totalPages = pages.value? (pages.value * 15) : 0;
var totalImages = images.value? (images.value * 10) : 0;
var totalGallery = 0;

if (gallery.checked == true){
totalGallery = 30 } 
else { totalGallery = 0}
var totalCost = 60 + totalPages + totalImages + totalGallery;
document.getElementById('displayTotal').innerHTML = "$" + totalCost;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="pages">
<input type="number" id="images">
<input type="checkbox" id="gallery">

<p>total: <span id="displayTotal"></span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried copy/pasting your code, but it still isn't working for me

Comment: console.log(pages.value, images.value, gallery.checked); (as per suggestion from another comment) returns "3 undefined".

console.log(displayCost); returns "Uncaught ReferenceError: displayCost is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13"

Comment: @Kirk when does it return undefined? when enter values in input box?

Comment: @Kirk where is this `displayCost` coming from? where you have used it in your code?

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot. I should have been running console.log(displayTotal); - which returns an HTMLCollection

Comment: @Kirk can't help you now without any new inputs from you, as you can it's working here in the code snippet. You have to debug and find whats wrong

Comment: Ok, I know where I was going wrong. The "displayTotal" ID is a text input field, not a standalone element, so I needed to have `document.getElementById('displayTotal').value = "$" + totalCost;` instead of `.innerHTML`. The calculation is now executing, however, the checkbox is adding 0 to the calculation, instead of 30?

Comment: @Kirk `console.log(gallery.checked)` before `if` statament and see what you get

Comment: Thanks for your patience here. `console.log(gallery.checked)` returns `undefined`

Comment: @Kirk make sure `var gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');` this line is there in your code and make sure there are not spelling mistakes in the "gallery" as it can also be spelled "gallary"